# Pasting link of my homepage to FB wall does not display OpenGraph excerpt, OG meta tags are present

Tags: seo, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I am currently working on our website, which I am publishing using WordPress and the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin. I have checked the HTML source and the OpenGraph meta information is present:

screenshot of html source of our site www.verstrickt.at here: [image]

However when I post the link to my wall the only thing it displays is:

screenshot of posted link on FB wall:

[image]

Anyone any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: you shave the url set to the root domain, and the type set to article,  your root domain should be set to either website or blog only.  All others should be article or what they represent.  see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#types

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL using Facebook's debugger tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug